# Cross-compile .NET project from Gitlab-runner to Windows

Tags: c#, .net, gitlab, devops, cross-compiling

I'm new to DevOps. I'm trying to set up an automated deploy pipeline for .NET project. I would like to build this project and copy it to remote Windows machine for manual testing.

I have most of my work done. But my biggest problem (I guess) have something to do with cross-compilation. It all just works on my Windows computer (I can build and run the project with an IDE) but I'm not able to correctly compile it on GitLab-runner.

---

I have following `.gitlab-ci.yml` config:

```yaml
image: mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0
stages:
  - build
  - test
  - deploy

build_job:
  stage: build
  script:
    - dotnet build -o ../build
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - build

test_job:
  stage: test
  script:
    - dotnet test --no-build -o ../build

deploy_job:
  stage: deploy
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH
  script:
    - dotnet publish MyProject.sln -o ../publish
    # copy ../publish to a remote server
```

I commented out the last part as it is not relevant (it just copies files with `sftp`).

I have stage `build` that kind of works, but kind of not. It builds *something*, but it does not generate EXE files. And I'm trying to reuse this build during testing stage.

In `deploy` stage I decided to use `dotnet publish` instead of `dotnet build` hoping that maybe it will give me correct result. I tried many different approaches and many different flags but at the end I'm just not able to compile this project on GitLab runner, so that I can copy output folder over to a Windows machine and run the EXE file.

---

If I run
`dotnet publish -o ../publish`

I get:

> /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/5.0.402/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.CrossTargeting.targets(27,5): error NETSDK1129: The 'Publish' target is not supported without specifying a target framework. The current project targets multiple frameworks, you must specify the framework for the published
> application.

So I tired and specify framework like this:
`dotnet publish -o ../publish -f net5.0`

But then I get:

> /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/5.0.402/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets(241,5): error NETSDK1005: Assets file '/builds/myuser/myrepo/myproject/Common/obj/project.assets.json' doesn't have a target for 'net5.0'. Ensure that restore has run and that you have included 'net5.0' in the TargetFrameworks for your project.

So I tried also running `dotnet restore --force` beforehand but to everyone's surprise that didn't changed a thing (still the same error) - yes I know restore should be implicitly called anyway.

It started 'successfully' compiling only after I added explicit path to my solution file.
`dotnet publish MyProject.sln -o ../publish`

But it does not generate any EXE files.

---

What am I missing? I don't know what I'm doing wrong. I'm kinda new to not only DevOps but .NET also. How can I compile this project on Gitlab-runner so that it will work on Windows?

Answer (score 0):

You should specify the `.csproj` file for publish command and also consider the `Runtime Identifier (RID)` for output format (for windows 8 the RID is win8-x64 and it generates .exe file) like this:

```
script: 
    - dotnet restore path/to/yourProject.csproj
    - dotnet publish path/to/yourProject.csproj -c Release -r win8-x64 -o ../build
```

Comment: That didn't work either.  `/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/5.0.402/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.targets(993,5): error NETSDK1150: The referenced project '../MyProject.SubProject/MyProject.SubProject.csproj' is a non self-contained executable.  A non self-contained executable cannot be referenced by a self-contained executable.`

Comment: @AnJ The error says you are trying to publish a project that is not a console application or web application.